# Peter Norvigs spellcheck in Rust

Tags: strings, rust

For a Rust project I'm working on I needed a (simple) spellcheck algorithm and I set out to re-implement [Peter Norvigs spellcheck algorithm](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) in Rust.

```
extern crate regex;

use regex::Regex;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::iter::FromIterator;
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

static ALPHABET : &'static str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

fn deletes(s: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    (0..s.len())
        .map(|i| {
            let mut delete = s.to_owned();
            delete.remove(i);

            delete
        })
        .collect()
}

fn inserts(s: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    (0..s.len() + 1)
        .flat_map(|i| {
            ALPHABET.chars().map(|chr| {
                let mut insert = s.to_owned();
                insert.insert(i, chr);

                insert
            }).collect::<Vec<_>>()
        })
        .collect()
}

fn replaces(s: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    (0..s.len())
        .flat_map(|i| {
            ALPHABET.chars().map(|chr| {
                let mut replace = String::with_capacity(s.len());
                replace.push_str(&s[0..i]);
                replace.push(chr);
                replace.push_str(&s[i + 1..]);

                replace
            }).collect::<Vec<_>>()
        })
        .collect()
}

fn transposes(s: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();

    (1..bytes.len())
        .map(|i| {
            let mut transpose = bytes.to_owned();
            transpose.swap(i - 1, i);

            String::from_utf8(transpose).expect("Invalid UTF-8")
        })
        .collect()
}

fn read_dictionary_words(dictionary_path: &str) -> String {
    let mut buffer = String::new();

    File::open(&Path::new(dictionary_path))
        .unwrap()
        .read_to_string(&mut buffer)
        .unwrap();

    buffer
}

fn word_count(all_words: &str) ->  HashMap<String, u32> {
    let re = Regex::new(r"\w+").unwrap();
    let lowercase = all_words.to_lowercase();

    let mut map = HashMap::new();

    for word in re.captures_iter(&lowercase) {
        // arg, the to_owned is pretty nasty here, as it creates a new owned string every time ...
        *map.entry(word[0].to_owned()).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }

    map
}

fn edits1(s: &str) -> HashSet<String> {
    deletes(s)
        .into_iter()
        .chain(replaces(s).into_iter())
        .chain(transposes(s).into_iter())
        .chain(inserts(s).into_iter())
        .collect()
}

fn edits2(s: &str) -> HashSet<String> {
    edits1(s)
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|e| edits1(e))
        .collect()
}

fn calc_p(word: &str, wc: &HashMap<String, u32>) -> f32 {
    if !wc.contains_key(word) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    let total:u32 = wc.values().sum();
    wc[word] as f32 / total as f32
}

fn known(candidates: HashSet<String>, wc: &HashMap<String, u32>) -> HashSet<String> {
    candidates
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|w| wc.contains_key(w))
        .collect::<HashSet<_>>()
}

fn create_candidates(s: &str, wc: &HashMap<String, u32>) -> HashSet<String> {
    if wc.contains_key(s) {
        return HashSet::from_iter(vec![s.to_owned()].into_iter());
    }

    let candidates = known(edits1(s), wc);

    if candidates.len() > 0 {
        return candidates;
    }

    let candidates = known(edits2(s), wc);

    if candidates.len() > 0 {
        return candidates;
    }

    HashSet::new()
}

fn correction(candidates: HashSet<String>, wc: &HashMap<String, u32>) -> Vec<(f32, String)> {
    let mut weighted_candidates = candidates
        .into_iter()
        .map(|w| (calc_p(&w, &wc), w))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    weighted_candidates.sort_by(|a, b| b.partial_cmp(a).unwrap());

    weighted_candidates
}

fn main() {
    // This is the file from http://www.norvig.com/big.txt
    let all_words = read_dictionary_words("/tmp/big.txt");
    let wc = word_count(&all_words);

    let corrections = correction(create_candidates("speling", &wc), &wc);
    println!("{:?}", corrections.first().unwrap());

    let corrections = correction(create_candidates("korrectud", &wc), &wc);
    println!("{:?}", corrections.first().unwrap());
}
```

The output is:

```
(0.0000035855628, "spelling") // suggestion for "speling"
(0.00001254947, "corrected")  // suggestion for "korrectud"
```

Which seems to be roughly in line with what Peters Python version does.

The code is basically runnable, but you need to have the file `big.txt` which contains words from various text sources combined into one blob. The file can be found [here](http://www.norvig.com/big.txt) (BEWARE: 6.5 MB text file ahead!)

- I refactored already the `deletes`, `transposes`, `inserts`, `replaces` functions thanks to [another code review here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155294/transposing-characters-in-a-string).
- In general I would be interested if I got ownership right. I fought less with the borrow checker this time however.
- There is a line in the `word_count` function that's particular nasty, it does a string allocation every time for checking if the key is in the `HashMap` but puts it in only once.
- The performance is OK for my usecase but not really impressive.

All other comments/suggestions are welcome, too, of course.

My usecase is only about ASCII strings. I thought about using the `ASCII` crate types to make that explicit, but not in this version, it's a fair suggestion of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments, since no one else has posted here:

Set up some proper error handling so you don't have so many `unwraps` and `expects`. I think the `error_chain` crate is the recommended/most popular way to do error handling, but is probably overkill for your case. However, `error_chain` also provides the `quick_error` macro, which allows you to easily define your own errors and wrap external errors. For very, very basic handling you can just do:

```
pub mod err {
    quick_error! {
        #[derive(Debug)]
        pub enum Error {
            Other(err: Box<::std::error::Error + Send + Sync>) {
                from(e: &'static str) -> (e.into())
                from(e: ::std::io::Error) -> (e.into())                
                description(err.description())
                display("{}", err)
            }    
        }
    }
    pub type Result<T> = ::std::result::Result<T, Error>;
}
```

And then wrap your functions in `Result<_>`, and you can use `try`/`?` everywhere.

---

Not really a big deal for your case since you only call it once, but it is good practice to wrap `Regex::new` in `lazy_static` to avoid compiling it multiple times, e.g.:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref RE: Regex = Regex::new(r"\w+").unwrap();
}
```

---

You can work around the String allocation with the Entry API like (not sure if  there is a more graceful way to do this...):

```
for word in re.captures_iter(&lowercase) {
    let word0 = word[0];
    if let Some(e) = map.get_mut(word0) {
        *e += 1;
        continue;
    }
    map.insert(word0.into(), 1);
}
```

---

I would suggest returning an `Option` or `Result` from `known` where the empty case returns a `None` like type, so that you don't have to check `candidates.len() > 0` multiple times in `create_candidates`. You could chain the different candidates then return the default if none apply.

---

ALSO! If your performance seems bad, make sure that you are doing `cargo run --release` or `cargo build --release` to run your program.

Hope this helps—

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for my late response. I think you made good points, I wil have a look!